# How do you programatically instantiate a subclassed ViewController in MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have subclassed a ViewController that was created via XCode Interface Builder. my subclass is defined like so

```
public MyViewControllerGeneric<T> : MyViewController{
    public MyViewControllerGeneric(IntPtr handle) : base(handle){}
}
```

I can use Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MyViewController") to get an instance of MyViewController. However how do I create an instance of MyViewControllerGeneric and pass a handle to it?

Tried

```
var vc = new MyViewControllerGeneric<MyType>(this.Handle)
var vc = new MyViewControllerGeneric<MyType>(new IntPtr(DateTime.Now.Ticks)
```

both throw a SigAbort

Any Help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IntPtr` handle is not something you should be passing in.

Use this constructor instead:

```
public MyViewControllerGeneric<T> : MyViewController{
    public MyViewControllerGeneric() : base(){ }
}
```

Or this if you need a NIB loaded, depending on your base class:

```
public MyViewControllerGeneric<T> : MyViewController{
    public MyViewControllerGeneric() : base("MyViewControllerGeneric", null){ }
}
```

Comment: Well, after denining a default constructor on MyViewController I was able to use what you suggested above. But the View does not display. I get a black screen when Present the ViewControllerGeneric

Comment: See my edit above, you may need to do this depending on what you have setup in your non-generic class.

Comment: Would the technique be any different if using Storyboard? MyViewController is the auto generated (By MonoTouch framework) ViewController class.

Comment: If you create an instance of the base class, does it work?  If so, you need to use the same constructor that works.

Comment: The base class would be instantiated via the Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("viewControllerID") and that works. However I am trying to make the code "generic" so I can use the same view controller for different types of searches. Basically I am trying to create generic Search View Controller wherein I pass the type that's being searched via the constructor. Want to avoid creating a bunch of search view controlles who just differ by what they are searching

Comment: I'm afraid that probably won't work unless someone from Xamarin chimes in.  I would not think that `InstantiateViewController` would be able to supply generic arguments to a C# object.  Can you do this a different way?  Perhaps use the same controller object, but pass a `SearchProvider<T>` object you create to the controller for this functionality.

Comment: yep, that's what I ended up doing. Created a "delegate" class that does the actual type specific searches. Wanted to be sure if I wasn't missing something basic. Thanks for your time.